# WhenEvent with a function

Tags: map, event-detection

I have the the function

```
kill[x_]:=Map[#->0&,x]
```

which is supposed to set a list of functions to zero. That seems to be working, because

```
kill[{a,b}]
```

yields

```
{a->0,b->0}
```

but when I want to use this in a WhenEvent[] Environment it remains unevaluated.
The function that I use is

```
wepr[f1_,x_]:=WhenEvent[f1==0,kill[x]]
```

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you!

---

EDIT:

Please consider: for easier reading, i wrote rel1 instead of Subscript[rel,i], so the index does work.

I have a table which creates the equations for my set of ODEs

```
eqns = DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@Table[{
reli'[t]==...,

relj'[r]==...,

wepr[reki[t], {cri[t], reli[t]}]

,{i,1,Nre},{j,1,Npr}]
```

Which I then solve in

```
NDSolve[eqns,...]
```

This all works fine.

I want to set the functions cr1[t] and rel1[t] to zero as soon as rek1[t] reaches zero.
This works totally fine, when I write

```
wepr[f1_,f2_,f3_]:=WhenEvent[f1==0,{f2->0,f3->0}]
```

however this code needs to be adaptable.

Comment: Can you provide the syntax you use to run the function? & expected output? Thanks!

Comment: From `WhenEvent` doc: WhenEvent expressions can be used in NDSolve, NDSolveValue, ParametricNDSolve, ParametricNDSolveValue, DSolve, and DSolveValue.

Comment: @Fortsaint It is part of a NDSolve[ ] Environment. I have added some additional explanation

Comment: @CATrevillian sure thing! Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Wolfgang, what do you mean when you say the code needs to be adaptable? Accept any length of `f_2,f_3,f_4,...,f_n` input?

Comment: @CATrevillian exactely! The model is ever changing... unfortunately ^^

Comment: @WolfgangSchneider I posted an answer, let me know if this works for you, & if not, what the outcome is.

Comment: `WhenEvent` (in `*NDSolve*[]` functions) can be finicky. Like `Manipulate`. They both rewrite your code before executing it. The rules literally present in `action` in `WhenEvent[event, action]` are replaced by ``NDSolve`SetState[]`` expressions for use in a function that handles the event. Since the literal, unevaluated expression `kill[x]` has no rules in it, no `SetState[]` actions will be included in the internal event function and nothing happens. It is unfortunate that it does not write the event function on the fly during integration, but the action is set before integration starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a rule for the `WhenEvent` action. Here's a silly example that kills whichever of the variables is greatest. Note that `NDSolve` passes the values of the variables to `annihilateMax[v]`, not the variable names.  So it returns a vector of numbers, with the greatest number replace by `0.`.

```
annihilateMax[v_] := v /. Max[v] -> 0.;

vars = Array[v, 4]; (* change 4 to get a different number of variables *)
varst = Through[vars[t]];
{sol} = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -y[t], y'[t] == x[t], x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0,
    D[varst, t] == RotateLeft[varst]/12, 
    Through[vars[0]] == RandomReal[1, Length@vars],
    WhenEvent[y[t] == 0 && x[t] > 0, # -> annihilateMax[#]] &@varst},
   vars~Join~{x, y}, {t, 0, 40}];

Plot[varst /. sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 40}]
```

[image]

Not really sure what you want.  To kill some variables you could use this:

```
WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, # -> 0*#]] &@ {x[1][t], x[4][t]}
```

That may be closer to how you intend to use `kill`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `fn` will need to be in a list if they are singular. This is why I use `Flatten@List@fn`.

Maybe this will work for you?

```
wepr[f1_, fn___] := WhenEvent[f1 == 0, Evaluate[Rule[#, 0] & /@ Flatten@List@fn]];
```

Which works like this:

```
wepr[0, 1]
```

> WhenEvent[0 == 0, {1 -> 0}]

```
wepr[0, {1, 2, 3}]
```

> WhenEvent[0 == 0, {1 -> 0, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 0}]

```
wepr[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

> WhenEvent[0 == 0, {1 -> 0, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 0}]

Hope this helps!